# Having problems with aligning images like I want

Tags: css, alignment

Basically want I want is for my large image to be to the left of my two small images, and I want my two small images to be stacked on top of one another. Currently I'm running the class "small-images" with a width of 30% because it makes them stack like I want, but I feel there is a better way to do this. Also these three images are going to run next to some text which is why I have all of them in one big div together so I can float them to the right of the main text. I don't mind if you take my code apart I'm trying to find the most efficient way possible and I'm using HTML5 and CSS3.

HTML5

```
<div class="images">
    <div class="large-image">

        <!--This is a larger image-->
        <img alt="bussiness lage picture" src="Images/buisness-big.jpg">

            <div class="small-image">
            <!--These are two smaller images-->
            <img alt="bussiness lage picture" src="Images/handshake.jpg">
            <img alt="bussiness lage picture" src="Images/calculator.jpg">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS 3

```
/*This deals with the main images right of the main content*/
.images {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.large-image {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.small-image {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: close your large-image div after the large image rather than encapsulating the small images too - http://jsfiddle.net/NNjY8/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this kind of structure :

```css
.images {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.images img {
    float: left;
}
.images .thumbs {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.images .thumbs img {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <aside class="images">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300/2ecc71/fff"/>
        <div class="thumbs">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/145/3498db/fff"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/145/e74c3c/fff"/>
        </div>
    </aside>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis suscipit dolorum repellat eveniet error a aliquam magni laudantium pariatur adipisci quisquam nesciunt unde quo. Quae ab explicabo et iure minus id ad placeat ducimus eos delectus assumenda recusandae labore! Minus modi error. Illo mollitia consequuntur ipsam fugit voluptatibus eos repudiandae!
</article>
```

Comment: Wow that's really cool, I'm going to work on that a bit and see if i can arrange it a bit more to my liking, thank you for this.